# Select option dropdown with Node.js, MySQL and EJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, ejs

I would like to make a drop-down list with the data from my MySQL database, in this case I am trying to make when filling out my "create budgets" form to extract the names from the "customer" table and place them in a select option, I'm using EJS. However, I also have problems when passing EJS data since it gives me an error in the browser (Data not defined)

This is my controller to save data:

```
controller.save = function(req, res, next) {
const data = req.body;
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query('SELECT nombre FROM clientes', (err, row) =>{
        res.render('presupuestos_create', {
            datos: row
        })
    });
    conn.query('INSERT INTO presupuestos set ?', [data], (err, row) => {
        res.redirect('/presupuestos');
    });
});
```

};

And this is mi EJS:

```
                <form action="/presupuestos/add" method="POST">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="cliente" class="form-label">Cliente</label>
                    <select  class="form-select" id="cliente" name="cliente" tabindex="1" required>
                        <option>----</option>
                        <%for(var i=0; i < datos.length; i++){%>
                            <option value="<%= datos[i] %>"><%= datos[i] %></option>
                        <%}%>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
to populate from db > ejs 

 <select  class="form-select" id="cliente" name="cliente" value="<%= datos%>" tabindex="1" required>
<% for(var i=0; i < datos.length; i++) { %>
  <option 
      <%= datos[i].datos %>
  </option>
<%}%>
```